# WebRTC iOS: remote video is not shown in iOS client

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I am trying to implement WebRTC in an iOS application using GoogleWebRTC pod. i can place a video call between iOS app and a web client, in which case the audio/video works just fine. however when i place a video call between two iOS devices there is no video(audio works). i've checked if there is remote stream and there is.

```
let localStream = connectionFactory?.mediaStream(withStreamId: "StreamID")
let audioTrack = connectionFactory?.audioTrack(withTrackId: "AudioTrackID")
let videoSource = connectionFactory?.avFoundationVideoSource(with: mediaConstraint)
let videoTrack = connectionFactory?.videoTrack(with: videoSource!, trackId: "VideoTrackID")
localStream?.addAudioTrack(audioTrack!)
localStream?.addVideoTrack(videoTrack!)
peerConnection?.add(localStream!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I was giving a hard coded string as id when creating stream and video track. which when a connection is established becomes the same for both local and remote streams. providing unique strings as ids solves the problem.

Comment: I don't think that's it. I have the same track ids and stream ids on both of my peers and they connect and transfer data with no problem

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then, cause whenever i give a static string value in the ids video doesn't work. but giving a dynamic value that'll be unique from other peers works

Comment: @guru no I think it was this: let videoTrack = connectionFactory?.videoTrack(with: videoSource!, trackId: "VideoTrackID")

Comment: @guru, my issue was that the "trackID" for VideoTrack on both sides were the same. they have to be different.

Comment: videoTrackIDs should be different on each end. if device A and B are connected, then the videoTrackIDs on each device should be different. if it already is, then there are some other issue. in my case videoTrackIDs were the issue.

Comment: sorry, i dont think so because the trackId always need to be this format:
let kARDMediaStreamId = "ARDAMS"
let kARDAudioTrackId = "ARDAMSa0"
let kARDVideoTrackId = "ARDAMSv0"

Answer (score 1):

As my understanding, you can add a remote video track when first create your local video track, then video track will auto produce frames when it is receiving from peer connection, an example code from WebRTC iOS client:

```
- (void)createMediaSenders {
    RTCMediaConstraints *constraints = [self defaultMediaAudioConstraints];
    RTCAudioSource *source = [_factory audioSourceWithConstraints:constraints];
    if (_isAudioEnabled) {
        RTCAudioTrack *track = [_factory audioTrackWithSource:source trackId:kDSAudioTrackId];
        [_peerConnection addTrack:track streamIds:@[ kDSMediaStreamId ]];
    }
    if (_isVideoEnabled) {
        _localVideoTrack = [self createLocalVideoTrack];
        if (_localVideoTrack) {
            [_peerConnection addTrack:_localVideoTrack streamIds:@[ kDSMediaStreamId ]];

            // Create remote video track
            RTCVideoTrack *track = (RTCVideoTrack *)([self videoTransceiver].receiver.track);
            [_delegate appRTC:self didReceiveRemoteVideoTrack:track];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in  func rtcClient(client : RTCClient, didReceiveRemoteVideoTrack remoteVideoTrack: RTCVideoTrack)
perform a selector that will call after 2 sec then in that selector add track to remoteview