# not able get video in many to many using webrtc in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I have created multiple peer connections and added common media streams to all peer connections. Exchange the `SDP` and `Candidate` via socket io. And I’m getting local video from the local media stream successfully but that stream is not showing on every peer connection, only last connected peer is able to show my stream

> **Create multiple Connection**

**RoomViewController**

```
for (index, peerId) in RoomViewController.arrPeers.enumerated() {
    if peerId != LocalStorage.myId?.vBarId{
        let webRTCClient = WebRTCClient.init(iceServers: config.webRTCIceServers, arrTurnServer: config.turnServers, strUserName: config.userName, strPassword: config.password, remoteId: peerId, signalClient: socketIoObject!, streamId: LocalStorage.myId?.vBarId ?? "")
        webRTCClient.delegate = self
        if index > myIndex{
            //offerCallToLowerPeers(client: webRTCClient, callFor: peerId)
        }else{
            webRTCClient.isAnswerAble = true
        }
        RoomViewController.arrPeerWebclients.append(webRTCClient)
    }
}
```

**WebRTCClient**

```
if arrTurnServer.count > 0{
            let trunServers = RTCIceServer.init(urlStrings: arrTurnServer, username:strUserName, credential: strPassword)
            config.iceServers = [RTCIceServer(urlStrings: iceServers), trunServers]
        }else{
            config.iceServers = [RTCIceServer(urlStrings: iceServers)]
        }

        //config.iceServers = [RTCIceServer(urlStrings: iceServers)]
        // Unified plan is more superior than planB
        config.sdpSemantics = .planB

        // gatherContinually will let WebRTC to listen to any network changes and send any new candidates to the other client
        config.continualGatheringPolicy = .gatherContinually

        let constraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: nil,
                                              optionalConstraints: ["DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement":kRTCMediaConstraintsValueTrue])
        self.peerConnection = WebRTCClient.factory.peerConnection(with: config, constraints: constraints, delegate: nil)
```

**Create local media stream**

```
            if RoomViewController.localMediaStream == nil{
                let audioTrack = self.createAudioTrack()
                print(audioTrack)
                self.peerConnection.add(audioTrack, streamIds: [streamId])


                let videoTrack = self.createVideoTrack()
                self.localVideoTrack = videoTrack

                let mediaStream = WebRTCClient.factory.mediaStream(withStreamId: streamId)
                mediaStream.addAudioTrack(audioTrack)
                mediaStream.addVideoTrack(videoTrack)
                RoomViewController.localMediaStream = mediaStream
            }

            self.peerConnection.add(RoomViewController.localMediaStream)
```

> **Local and remote video on view**

```
    guard let capturer = RoomViewController.arrPeerWebclients.first!.videoCapturer as? RTCCameraVideoCapturer else {
                return
            }

            guard
                let frontCamera = (RTCCameraVideoCapturer.captureDevices().first { $0.position == .front }),

                // choose highest res
                let format = (RTCCameraVideoCapturer.supportedFormats(for: frontCamera).sorted { (f1, f2) -> Bool in
                    let width1 = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(f1.formatDescription).width
                    let width2 = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(f2.formatDescription).width
                    return width1 < width2
                }).last,

                // choose highest fps
                let fps = (format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges.sorted { return $0.maxFrameRate < $1.maxFrameRate }.last) else {
                    return
            }

            capturer.startCapture(with: frontCamera,
                                  format: format,
                                  fps: Int(fps.maxFrameRate))

            let localVideoFrame = CGRect.init(x: 15, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
            #if arch(arm64)
            // Using metal (arm64 only)
            let localRenderer = RTCMTLVideoView(frame: localVideoFrame)
            localRenderer.videoContentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            #else
            // Using OpenGLES for the rest
            let localRenderer = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame: localVideoFrame)
            #endif


            RoomViewController.localMediaStream.videoTracks.first?.add(localRenderer)
            self.view.addSubview(localRenderer)

            for (index, stream) in RoomViewController.arrRemoteStreams.enumerated() {
                switch index {
                case 0:
                    #if arch(arm64)
                    // Using metal (arm64 only)
                    let remoteRenderer = RTCMTLVideoView(frame:  CGRect.init(x: 15, y: 300, width: 100, height: 100))
                    remoteRenderer.videoContentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                    #else
                    // Using OpenGLES for the rest
                    let remoteRenderer = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame:  CGRect.init(x: 15, y: 300, width: 100, height: 100))
                    #endif
                    stream.videoTracks.first?.add(remoteRenderer)
                    self.view.addSubview(remoteRenderer)
                case 1:
                    #if arch(arm64)
                    // Using metal (arm64 only)
                    let remoteRenderer = RTCMTLVideoView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 160, y: 300, width: 100, height: 100))
                    remoteRenderer.videoContentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                    #else
                    // Using OpenGLES for the rest
                    let remoteRenderer = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 160, y: 300, width: 100, height: 100))
                    #endif
                    stream.videoTracks.first?.add(remoteRenderer)
                    self.view.addSubview(remoteRenderer)

                default:
                    print("default case")
                }


}
```

**I have checked multiple answer mostly based on web not for ios**

[WebRTC iOS: remote video is not shown in iOS client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290365/webrtc-ios-remote-video-is-not-shown-in-ios-client)

Comment: Did you fix this issue ?

Comment: Yes @NikeshHyanju

Comment: could you please share your solution I am working on a video room using WebRTC and janus !
i have been stuck for weeks now.

Comment: could you please help?

Comment: there are lot of factors if you will share your sample then i will track easily. @NikeshHyanju